# Handling GET/POST/ PUT/ DELETE upcoming Requests in Base Class all together in Afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I have made a connection manager base class, which handles POST requests. But i have some request in GET and PUT.

**How i can to handle GET/POST/PUT through connection manager class in below Code.**

Let me know i am doing in right way to make request using void -

My Connection Manager Class, which handles only POST request -

**.h**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, HttpRequestMethod)
{
 HttpRequestMethodPOST,
 HttpRequestMethodGET
};

@interface VCConnectionManager : NSObject
+ (instancetype) sharedInstance;
- (void) actionmethod:(NSString *)action     parameters:(NSDictionary *)params  onComplete:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *json))successBlock onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation VCConnectionManager

+(instancetype) sharedInstance {
 DEFINE_SINGLETON_WITH_BLOCK(^{
 return [[VCConnectionManager alloc] init];
});
}

 - (void) actionmethod:(NSString *)action parameters:(NSDictionary *)param  onComplete:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *json))successBlock onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock {

 BOOL network = [self currentNetworkStatus];
 if(network){

        NSString     *weburl = WS_BASE_URL;
        NSString * completeRequestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", weburl,action];
        DDLogVerbose(@"Complete_URL--->%@",completeRequestUrl);
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
        [params setValue:@"0" forKey:@"loginType"];

       [manager POST:completeRequestUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
      successBlock(responseObject);
       DDLogVerbose(@"\n\n\n\nResponse Result---->%@",responseObject);
  }
  failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
      //DDLogVerbose(@"Error: %@", error);
      errorBlock(error);
  }];
 }
 else{
    UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:AppName message:NETWORK_ERROR delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [internetAlert show];
 }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why wouldn't you just replace the `POST` call with `GET` or `PUT` or whatever?

Comment: @Rob if service is get/post/put i have to handle it through singleton class connection manager. Depend on the request it should get changed. I have to manage all get/post/put request using singleton class. I have done only for post request. so it s there

Comment: @Rob  how can i know which request is get post or delete

Comment: Whether a request should be `POST` or `DELETE` or whatever is dictated by the web service API. So, in your case, a particular value for `action` would require a particular HTTP method. (As an aside, if dealing with JSON API, you generally just `POST`, though.)

Comment: @Rob could you post answer for it. How could i handle value for action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83499/discussion-between-imran-and-rob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method parameter and call it something like `methodType`. For brevity, I'm not `typedef`'ing this, but you should.

```
- (void)actionmethod:(NSString *)action methodType:(NSString*)methodType parameters:(NSDictionary *)param onComplete:(void (^)(NSMutableDictionary *json))successBlock onError:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock { // etc.
    ...
    if ([methodType isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        [manager POST:completeRequestUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)...
    } else if (([methodType isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        [manager GET:completeRequestUrl parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)...
    }
    // etc.
```

Comment: I understood ur way. but i am looking that all POST/GET/ method should be recognise in connection manager class . like enum kind of

Comment: It's specifically not designed that way because you'll be handling each type of request differently.

Comment: ok but i m looking for single manager class method will change depend on get post

Comment: You'll have to either fork the project then or create a helper category (or subclass).